# Prove that $K$ is finite Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

I just need a bit of quick help in understanding some solutions to a problem set.

The question is this:

(a) Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ a zero of $f(x) = x^3-3x+1$. Prove that $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I easily showed, $f(x)$ is irreducible, and detemined that is $\alpha$ s a root of $f(x)$, then so is $\alpha^2-2$. I was stuck, and the solutions says:

Let $\beta$ be a third zero of $f(x)$, then $\alpha + ( \alpha^2-2)+ \beta = 0$, since the coefficient of $x^2$ is zero in $f(x)$.

Why is this so? I am struggling to see this.

Comment: because the coefficient of the quadratic term is the sum of the roots of the degree $3$ polynomial. More generally: the sum of the roots of polynomial of degree $n$ is equal to minus the coefficient of the $n-1$ degree monomial (compare this to linear-algebra, where the $n-1$ term of the characteristic poly is given by $-$ the trace of the matrix). Following the same idea, the constant term is equal $(-1)^n$ times the product of all roots.

Comment: (to show this, just go to the algebraic closure and use (for example) induction on the degree of the poly)

Comment: Observe that $(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)(X-\gamma)=X^3-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)X^2+(\alpha\beta+\alpha \gamma+\beta\gamma)X-\alpha\beta\gamma$. Thus, in this case, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$, $\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=-3$, and $\alpha\beta\gamma=-1$ just as b00n heT said.

Comment: @Taylor - Direct and simple answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the discriminant? This is one way to show that K is Galois over the field of rational numbers.

Comment: This may be so, but it does not engage at all with the question OP asks.

Comment: Gerry, upon response of the OP, I plan to elaborate. I do not want to give a solution using methods the OP doesn't know. Do you recommend I delete the question, or do you think it is better suited as a comment? Thanks.

Comment: OP couldn't understand "coefficient of $x^2$ is zero, so the roots add up to zero." The discriminant has nothing to do with this. It is true that there is an entirely different way, using the discriminant, to show the field is Galois, and it is worth noting this --- but, yes, in a comment, not (in my opinion) in an answer.